# How to list heap permutation

Tags: java

I have function heap permutation
I want to have a list [[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2], [1, 2, 0], [0, 2, 1], [2, 0, 1], [2, 1, 0]] 
but my result is [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 2, 2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 0] Please help me thanks

```
public static  List<Integer> permute(int[] v, int n) {
        //write code here
        List b = new ArrayList();
            if (n==1) {
                for (int j=0 ; j<v.length ; j++) {
                    b.add(v[j]);
                    }
            }
            else {
                for (int i=0 ; i<n ; i++) {
                    permute(v,n-1);
                    if(n%2 == 0) swap(v,i,n-1);
                    else swap(v,0,n-1);
                }
            }
            return b;
        }
```

Comment: 1) Do not use *raw* generic objects, i.e. change `List<Integer> b = new ArrayList<>()`. 2) If you want a `List<List<Integer>>` as the result, why is your method returning a flat `List<Integer>`?

Comment: So, you want the function to return a list of lists, but your functions return type is a list?

Comment: How can your result be what you say, when your recursive call discards the return value?

Comment: what should i do ? i don't know about List<List<Integer>>

Answer (score 0):

<s>In python, because I can't test the java code right now, and python's easier to write up quickly, 

`def permute(list):
        if not list:
            return [[]]
        result = []
        for entry in permute(list[1:]):
            for i in range(len(entry)):
                result.append(entry[:i]+list[i:i+1]+entry[i:])
        return result`

I hope this helps, I'd have written java if I could test it.</s>

Here's an algorithm to do this. Stack Overflow isn't a site about doing other people's homework, so I won't give you the entire answer.
You'll want a function that takes in a list, and returns a list of lists.
Because you're solving this recursively, the first step is the base case. That means, if the problem has been reduced to it's simplest form, you should return the obvious answer. In this problem, the simplest form of the problem is when you call permute on the empty list, and the obvious answer is to return an empty list (make sure the list your return is the correct type).
Now that the base case is handled, we need to handle the general case, and just like in proofs by induction, you can assume your function works on smaller problems.
So, if you have a list [1,2,3,4], you can use your permute function on [2,3,4] and get the list of permutations of [2,3,4], and then for each of those permutations, you need to add 1 at each possible index.

Once you've gone through you smaller list you created with the recursive call to permute, and added the first value of your list to each index of each list returned by permute, you've finished, and you can return the list of all the lists you generated.

Comment: Can you convert it to java please